# How to compile RDiscount on Solaris?

Tags: ruby, unix, rubygems, solaris, markdown

I have a few Solaris 10 boxes and I'd like to have RDiscount running there. (They are Joyent accelerators, which have a somewhat customized, BSD-ish, userland, in case it matters.)

I'm aware of Maruku, rpeg-markdown and other ruby alternatives to BlueCloth, but initially I'd like to go with RDiscount.

Here's what I get when trying to install it:

```
    $ sudo gem install rdiscount
    Password:
    Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
    ERROR:  Error installing rdiscount:
            ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /opt/local/bin/ruby18 extconf.rb install rdiscount
    checking for random()... yes
    checking for srandom()... yes
    checking for funopen()... no
    checking for fopencookie()... no
    *** extconf.rb failed ***
    [snip]

    extconf.rb:11: No funopen or fopencookie support available. (RuntimeError)
```

Apparently the installation fails because it cannot find neither `funopen` nor `fopencookie`.

And to tell the truth, I have little idea what these are. So, any pointers on what I'd need to do to get this to compile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### update 2:

rdiscount 1.3.4 installs fine on Solaris, thanks to the help and hard work of the David Parsons, Ryan Tomayko, and the [Joyent team and community at their forums](http://discuss.joyent.com/viewtopic.php?id=25008).

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately `fopencookie` is part of glibc, and `glibc` has not been ported to Solaris.

Use a different gem.